# Number of equivalence classes based on a relation regarding a non-principal ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, model-theory, filters

We have an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ given by $$f\equiv g \iff \{n\in\mathbb{N}: f(n)=g(n)\}\in\mathbb{U},$$ where $\mathbb{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.

The question is to find the cardinality of the set of all equivalence classes. My guess would be $2^{\aleph_0}$, but, well, it is just a guess. I don't really know how to tackle this exercise, not even where to start...

What we know, I believe, is that all the sequences which differ on all the places but for one, are in separate equivalence classes (because the ultrafilter is non-principal). On the other hand, there might not be a $2$-element set in $\mathbb{U}$ as well, or $3$-element, $4$-element etc., which would give me that there are at most 
$$\sup_\limits{n\in\omega}\aleph_0^n = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph
_0}$$
equivalence classes (I count all the combinations of $n$-element sets). Hence my guess. Could be wrong though.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cardinal arithmetic is just wrong. $$\sup_{n\in\omega}\aleph_0^n=\sup_{n\in\omega}\aleph_0=\aleph_0\neq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}.$$

For your question, first show there exists a set $\cal A\subseteq P(\Bbb N)$, such that:

1. If $A,B\in\cal A$ then either $A=B$ or $A\cap B$ is finite.
2. $|\mathcal A|=2^{\aleph_0}$.
3. If $A\in\cal A$, then $A$ is not in the ultrafilter.

Now use $\cal A$ to construct a family of pairwise-distinct equivalence classes.

(Note that the third property is the easiest to satisfy, the first two guarantee that at most one member of $\cal A$ can be in the ultrafilter, so we can remove it and get the third property.)

Comment: I think I don't understand the overall idea behind the proof. Say, I have this $\mathcal{A}$. How does this help me? Do I want to find a correspondence between its elements and infinite sequences? Or... I'm sorry I don't see it yet.

Comment: You are looking for functions that every two disagree on a small set; finite sets are small sets. What will be the simplest functions you could define from sets into $\Bbb N$, and how does the fact that every two distinct sets have only finite intersection helps you here?

Comment: I could use identity, and I have no idea at all how finite intersection helps me here :( What I also find confusing is that it could happen some $A\in\{\mathcal{A}$ is finite. Then I see no connection with such a set and an infinite sequence.

Comment: How many finite sets are there? Most sets in $\cal A$ are not finite if $\cal A$ has cardinality continuum. The identity function is not a function defined on *all* $\Bbb N$. Moreover, you're not thinking about the *obvious* way of turning a subset of a domain into a function. Let me give you a hint, you only need *two* elements in the range of each function.

Comment: I... Ok, I'll think about what you said, thanks.

Comment: @Brian: At most one element of $\cal A$ can be in the ultrafilter. Therefore we can assume none of them is in the ultrafilter, in which case their union (and therefore their symmetric difference) is not in the ultrafilter either.

Comment: @Asaf: Ah, okay. Clearly I *wasn’t* thinking.

Comment: @Brian: Well, you had me scared there for a moment! :-)

Comment: Oh, I guess that third constraint does it. I could make a $0$-$1$ sequence with $1$'s on the places given by elements of $A\in\mathcal{A}$, is that what you had in mind? And then every such function is in separate class because no set from $\mathcal{A}$ is in the ultrafilter. So now I "just" have to prove $\mathcal{A}$ exists.

Comment: @Jules: Yes. Exactly. You can thank Brian for pointing out this missing link in the evolution of my thinking process.

Comment: Ok, so combining this and Brian's hint $\mathcal{A}=\{A: A=R_{f_x}, x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Is that right?

Comment: @Jules: For example.

Comment: Ok, great, immense thanks for your patience! And to @Brian for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ there is an injection $f_x:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that the sequence $\langle q_{f(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$. Consider $\{f_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: You suggest they are in separate classes?

Comment: @Jules: Yes; they're even in separate classes modulo the cofinite filter.

Comment: Is it simple to notice? :))) Because I see no contradiction is saying that, say, countably many are in one equivalence class.

Comment: Even uncountably many (because countably many doesn't hurt, right)

Comment: @Jules: If $x\ne y$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $f_x(n)\ne f_y(n)$ whenever $n\ge m$. Use the fact that $x$ and $y$ have disjoint open nbhds.